# Gnus shows all mail directories twice

Tags: gnus, email

I have Gnus set up to get mail via nnimap and it works fine, except for one small problem:  It shows all directories twice, once with a slash as the separator, once with a dot as the separator.  So I have a list that looks roughly like this:

```
12: Test/INBOX/Stackexchange
 *: Test.INBOX.Stackexchange
```

The directories with a dot as the separator are not subscribed, so at least I don't always see them, but they also cannot be opened (Emacs says they do not exist) and so they're pretty annoying.  Is there a way to get rid of them?  Maybe I need to delete some sort of cache to fix the problem.  I tried gnus-group-clear-data-on-native-groups, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test.INBOX.Stackexchange is the cached directory item stored at ~/.newsrc.eld.

You could delete the ~/.newsrc.eld and re-subscribe the mail folders from the scratch.

Personally I don't like ~/.newsrc.eld. I prefer explicitly specify the folders I want to subscribe in ~/.gnus.el.

So there is another solution by using gnus topics.

Insert below code into ~/.gnus.el

```
(add-hook 'gnus-group-mode-hook 'gnus-topic-mode)
(eval-after-load 'gnus-topic
  '(progn
     (setq gnus-message-archive-group '((format-time-string "sent.%Y")))
     (setq gnus-topic-topology '(("Gnus" visible)
                                 (("misc" visible))
                                 (("hotmail" visible nil nil))
                                 (("gmail" visible nil nil))))

     (setq gnus-topic-alist '(("hotmail" ; the key of topic
                               "nnimap+hotmail:Inbox"
                               "nnimap+hotmail:Drafts"
                               "nnimap+hotmail:Sent")
                              ("gmail" ; the key of topic
                               "INBOX"
                               "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
                               "Drafts")
                              ("misc" ; the key of topic
                               "nnfolder+archive:sent.2015-12"
                               "nnfolder+archive:sent.2016"
                               "nndraft:drafts")
                              ("Gnus")))))
```

BTW, you can check https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/gnus-guide-en.org

Comment: I deleted .newsrc as well for good measure (it contained the wrong directories as well).

Comment: .newsrc contains the statistics for each directory, it's OK to delete it too.